# Auth0 Single Sign On between Android app and wordpress website

Tags: php, android, wordpress, single-sign-on, auth0

We have implemented Auth0 and Lock on a native Android app and a wordpress website ( using the auth0 plugin )

For this puprose, two different clients have been created and the option "Use Auth0 instead of the IdP to do Single Sign On" is enabled.

The connections we use are database-username-password and facebook.
I am trying to find a way to the following:

- The user logs in to the Android app, either with username/password or
  facebook login.
- From within the app she clicks on a link that opens
  the default mobile browser ( not a webview ) and takes him to the
  wordpress website.
- The user is now at the wordpress website within her mobile browser ( e.g. chrome ). Since the user has already logged in to the android app and SSO is enabled we need to automatically log her in to the website without having to enter the username/password or login to facebook ( we assume that the mobile user will not be logged in to facebook on his browser )

I have read several Auth0 [SSO examples like this](https://auth0.com/docs/sso/regular-web-apps-sso) but everything refers to apps running on the browser ( where cookies are set and can be checked by the auth0 domain ).

I would like to know if the above scenario or a close alternative is possible and which Auth0 features I will need.